# Don't build docs from local hosted readthedocs

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am deploy local instance application readthedocs. When I'm start the generation of documentation appear errors.

Here logs:

```
29/May/2015 08:47:00] INFO [requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:180] Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
[29/May/2015 08:47:00] INFO [projects.tasks:87] (Build) [diclonius-doc:] Building
[29/May/2015 08:47:00] ERROR [projects.tasks:576] Unable to post a new build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/readthedoc/readthedocs/projects/tasks.py", line 574, in record_build
    api.build(build['id']).put(build)
  File "/srv/readthedoc/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slumber/__init__.py", line 164, in put
    resp = self._request("PUT", data=data, files=files, params=kwargs)
  File "/srv/readthedoc/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slumber/__init__.py", line 108, in _request
    raise exceptions.HttpClientError("Client Error %s: %s" % (resp.status_code, url), response=resp, content=resp.content)
HttpClientError: Client Error 401: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/build/7/
[29/May/2015 08:47:00] INFO [projects.tasks:209] (Build) [diclonius-doc:latest] Updating docs from VCS
...
...
[29/May/2015 08:47:01] INFO [vcs_support.base:66] VCS[diclonius-doc:latest]: 47973225b291c752663da75d5ba218e5423029c4

[29/May/2015 08:47:01] ERROR [projects.tasks:576] Unable to post a new build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/readthedoc/readthedocs/projects/tasks.py", line 574, in record_build
    api.build(build['id']).put(build)
  File "/srv/readthedoc/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slumber/__init__.py", line 164, in put
    resp = self._request("PUT", data=data, files=files, params=kwargs)
  File "/srv/readthedoc/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slumber/__init__.py", line 108, in _request
    raise exceptions.HttpClientError("Client Error %s: %s" % (resp.status_code, url), response=resp, content=resp.content)
HttpClientError: Client Error 401: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/build/7/
[29/May/2015 08:47:01] INFO [projects.tasks:308] (Build) [diclonius-doc:latest] Removing existing build dir
[29/May/2015 08:47:01] INFO [projects.utils:81] Running: 'virtualenv-2.7 -p python --no-site-packages /srv/readthedoc/user_builds/diclonius-doc/envs/latest' [/srv/readthedoc]
[29/May/2015 08:47:02] INFO [projects.utils:81] Running: '/srv/readthedoc/user_builds/diclonius-doc/envs/latest/bin/pip install --use-wheel --find-links=/srv/readthedoc/deploy/wheels -U  sphinx==1.3.1 Pygments==2.0.2 virtualenv==1.10.1 setuptools==1.1 docutils==0.11 mkdocs==0.11.1 mock==1.0.1 pillow==2.6.1 readthedocs-sphinx-ext==0.4.4 sphinx-rtd-theme==0.1.8 recommonmark==0.1.1' [/srv/readthedoc]
```

I am use server gunicorn and nginx for proxy.